# Objective-C block example needs explanation

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

I am new to Objective-C, I was following Apple's "Programming with Objective_C", I can't understand this code sample:

```
void (^(^complexBlock)(void (^)(void)))(void) = ^ (void (^aBlock)(void)) {
 //some code
 return ^{
 //some code
 };
};
```

I was expecting this pattern:

```
ReturnType ^(blockVariableIdentifier)(ParameterType1, ParameterType2, ...) = ^{  
   //some code
   };
```

1. How was `blockVariableIdentifier` repleaced with `(^complexBlock)(void (^)(void))` ?
2. isn't it supposed to have `void` as a return, how come that we have `return { ... }` ?

I find this code confusing, can you explain it ?

code [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW1).

**Update:**

Given this typedef:

`typedef void (^XYZSimpleBlock)(void);`

I can simplify the declaration of `complexBlock` to:

`void (^(^complexBlock)(XYZSimpleBlock))(void);`

but I still can't figure out how this is equivalent to

`XYZSimpleBlock (^betterBlock)(XYZSimpleBlock);`

Comment: It's confusing, what don't you understand? Or, maybe it's easier, could you write down what you think/understand/don't understand ? That way we can simply correct where you're wrong and not downvote, because it looks like you didn't put much effort in this :P

Comment: @AmrLotfy I updated my answer with `typedef` of `XYZSimpleBlock` and some explanation on return types

Comment: You can find the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057215/understanding-complex-block-syntax).

Answer (score 4):

It is said right there at your [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW1):

> The complexBlock variable refers to a block that takes another block as an argument (aBlock) and returns yet another block.

This is just block that returns another block. There is also simplification of that code:

```
typedef void (^XYZSimpleBlock)(void);
XYZSimpleBlock (^betterBlock)(XYZSimpleBlock) = ^(XYZSimpleBlock aBlock) {
    ...
    return ^{
        ...
    };
};
```

Return type of `betterBlock` is `XYZSimpleBlock` so you return another block from there. `void` relates only for `XYZSimpleBlock`, look at its `typedef` - block that have no arguments and do not return anything

Also [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201774/1565335) will be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22057215/1356559) (found in @Ahmed Lotfy's comment above) this is just a matter of language/compiler design, but to visuailze how that happened I made this image:

1. The expected syntax (top) of a block that takes a block as argument and returns a block, that is not accepted by Xcode.
2. The desgined syntax (bottom).

[image]

Visually what happened is just cutting the boxed `)(void)` and putting it at the end.

we can see it as analogy to a functin returning a block:

```
void (^f())(void) { 
 return ^{ ... }; 
}
```

just by substituting `f()` with `(^myBlock)(void (^) (void))` which is a block taking another block as a parameter with no return.

I hope we can live with that.